# Request permission from service in Android Auto

Tags: android, android-auto

My app is running in Android Auto and requires acces to storage to work. Without this permission it can do nothing.
How to ask permission to read and write storage from Android Auto.
The permission request needs an activity and I have to do it from the service.
I know it is possible because Google Maps can ask location permission from AA when it is not given.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a companion activity that will run on the mobile device instead, which provides the initialization interface for the user to accept all necessary permissions. The access to do this like Google Maps, isn’t available in the [Public SDK](https://developer.android.com/auto/). If necessary, and depending on the functionality of the app, you can show error messages to the user that they must allow access before being able to use the app.

Comment: One such example of an message to the user from a sample media app is at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312277/how-to-customize-hello-message-for-media-app-in-android-auto